# Slim Cache Options

Tags: php, slim

I have been looking for tutorials on how to cache responses on Slim (note that I am looking for responses Memcached, Redis, etc) but I would like an option that is viable on a shared host. I tried a couple of things but none of them seem to work. Also, I was thinking that I could create my own middlewar. If so, please point me in the right direction. This are some of the articles I have tried:

https://github.com/soupmix/cache-base/blob/master/README.md

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html

For those that like to say "what have you, try something, or the like" I would like to mention that I have finish my application using Slim. I just would like to know how I can start on the caching part.

Comment: You could use a file cache like this one: https://github.com/SamNicholson/slimfilecache This stores the cache in simple files on the server without the need for a dedicated caching service like redis/memcached etc.

Answer (score 0):

On a shared host, a file cache is the obvious answer. As FMK says, Sam Nicholson's [SlimFileCache](https://github.com/SamNicholson/slimfilecache) is a logical choice.

Also, you could roll your own using [zend-cache](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-cache), [Gregwar/Cache](https://github.com/Gregwar/Cache) or [Stash](https://github.com/tedious/Stash).